# Docker Desktop 3.1.0 installation issue - access is denied

Tags: docker, installation, access-denied, docker-desktop

I am trying to install Docker Desktop to my Windows 10 Professional Build 19042 and receive an installation error even when trying to install as 'Administrator'.

Error: Component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction failed: Failed to start service: Access is denied ...it is not clear to me what specifically Docker cannot access.

Curious to see if anyone has a solution to this issue.

[image: Docker 3.1.0 Installation issue]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add your account to the "docker-users" group.  See
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/785, especially nfunky response on Aug 10, 2020.  I used the following command and it resolved that problem for me where "username" is your Windows username:
net localgroup "docker-users" "username" /add

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled), first you should control the requirements based on your operating system. Next, uninstall the older versions. For example if you are using windows OS, look at this picture

[image]

and make sure these items are active in advance.

plus, make sure Hyper-V is installed and working (check the link above).
Finally, if you have this error message while opening the docker desktop:

> You are not allowed to use Docker. You must be in the “docker-users” group

you should add your user to docker-users named group created under Computer Management/user and groups/groups. look at this [link](https://jermsmit.com/you-are-not-allowed-to-use-docker-you-must-be-in-the-docker-users-group/)